# Is it safer to use a VM and VPN for working with other people's python scripts or executables?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, security, python, malware

I want to start taking freelancing jobs doing python programming, but I am new to working for others. I want to do everything I can to avoid scams and having my computer infected with malware. I know basic red flags like people trying to circumvent the website. But this question is more targeted to these ideas:

1. Should I use a virtual machine to modify or run people's scripts? I know there may possibly be crossover between the host and virtual environment, but it seems like a good defense just in case.
2. Do python scripts have the potential to be malicious after compilation?
3. I am considering wiping an old laptop to work on these jobs so that my nice PC won't get compromised. Is this overkill?
4. For malware that work by spreading over the network, is there a way to stay safe? Does a VPN protect my other devices? Or perhaps I can work without an internet connection if handling scripts or converting them to executables.

I'm somewhat computer savvy but not very experienced with VMs, VPNs, or protecting myself from scammers. I want to be safe and learn more, but if these steps are overkill, don't be afraid to call me in on that.

I have looked into the problem for a couple hours, but honestly, I'm not entirely sure I'm asking the right questions.

Comment: Transmission of data over a good VPN secures the transmission of said data. Otherwise the security concerns are yours to fulfill. I have used VMs for decades. I do not see VMs as being inherently more secure.

Comment: To clarify or expand on what John said: Using a VPN does not "sanitize" what is sent over that VPN or protect the systems on either end of that VPN from each other. Code doesn't morph during compilation, becoming something other than what it was: it won't become malicious after compilation if it was not before. Compilation would allow the code to run without the need for the Python runtimes on the target system.

Comment: The best security is a turned off, disconnected, and disassembled computer. Assuming some basic level of functionality, air-gapping is probably OK. A good firewall and security software running on VM and host is probably the best balance of function and security. You can use the virtual network to isolate and control network communication easily and conveniently. But, I think you need to exercise your own best tool: knowledge and code inspection. Know what you're working with, and know it well, BEFORE you run any of it. Whatever architecture you choose, knowledge and care is best.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.